# How can I set width to td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I keep `cell phone` words in the same line?

```css
.label {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

.input {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
}

.input > input {
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
}
```

```html
<form class="frm-find-people">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">Cell Phone</td>
                <td class="input"><input type="text" name="name"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

As you see, I've set `width: 300px` for that column. But seems it doesn't apply. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to `.label`:

```css
.label {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.input {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
}

.input > input {
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
}
```

```html
<form class="frm-find-people">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">Cell Phone</td>
                <td class="input"><input type="text" name="name"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

the `300px` width is not being applied because you have a `width:100%` on the next column, which tells it to occupy as much space as it can.

To fix that, you have to remove the `width:100%` on the next `td`. Transfer that to the text field instead. Finally, set the entire table to have `width:100%` so it covers the entire parent. Below is the corrected CSS.

```
table {
    width: 100%; /* This should be 100% */
}
    .label {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

.input {
    border: 1px solid red;
    /* remove width 100% from here */
}

.input > input {
  width: 100%; /* this should be 100% */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set `.input` to `width: 100%`, which is shrinking `.label` down to the smallest size possible (the length of the words inside)

You could use css calc to make `.input` 100vw - 300px wide

```
.input {
    width: calc(100vw - 300px);
}
```

And

```
.input > input {
  width: calc(100vw - 300px);
}
```

```css
.label {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 300px;
}

.input {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: calc(100vw - 300px);
}

.input > input {
  width: calc(100vw - 300px);
}
tr {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<form class="frm-find-people">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">Cell Phone</td>
                <td class="input"><input type="text" name="name"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: @MartinAJ How's my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use following css:

table { width:100%; } .label { width: 30%; padding: 5px 15px; } .input { border: 1px solid red; width:70%; } .input > input { width: calc(100% - 4px); }

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code, is that you should have:

```
table.mytable {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Because the `<td>` is a child element of the `<table class="mytable">`. So the parent element  has to have a set size to be able to modify child elements such as `<td>`. The added `mytable` class is so that it only affects that table incase you have others.